# UIViewController containment

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to use the UIViewController containment feature in one of my projects. The app is meant to be used in landscape mode only.

I add UIViewController **A** as a child of UIViewController **B** and add **A**'s main view as a subview of one of **B**'s views. I'm also saving a reference to A in B:

```
@interface BViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) AViewController *aVC;

@end

@implementation BViewController : UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.aVC = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];
    [self addChildViewController:self.aVC];
    [self.myContainerView addSubview:self.aVC.view];
}

@end
```

The problem I have is that landscape orientation is not being respected. I did some debugging and found a solution, but I fear is not ideal as it's more of a hack:

In B:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.aVC = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];
    [self addChildViewController:self.aVC];
    [self.myContainerView addSubview:self.aVC.view];
    [self.aVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

In A:

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parentVC
{
    // Interchange width and height
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.**height**, self.view.frame.size.**width**);
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code:

```
self.aVC = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];
[self addChildViewController:self.aVC];
[self.myContainerView addSubview:self.aVC.view];
```

was always wrong. You MUST send `didMoveToParentViewController:` to the child controller after adding it to the parent. See my discussion here:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

As for the rotation, it is probable that you're just doing all this too early. The app starts out in portrait and hasn't rotated yet to landscape when `viewDidLoad` is called. I give solutions to this problem here:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_rotation

Note the suggestion there that you wait until `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` to finish setting up your view's appearance. I think you might be facing here the same issues I'm describing there.